# Are unequal 5ths going from i to ii°6 acceptable in 4 part harmony?

Tags: voice-leading, satb

[image]

Im major this wouldn't work but in minor usually a P5 to a D5 is permitted right?

Comment: Acceptable in what context? Surely this is a subjective question, answerable by "does it sound good"?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this answer really depends on who/what you're learning from, because there are different schools of thought:

- Some say that parallel fifths are okay as long as one of the fifths is not perfect. As such, your part writing is correct.
- Others specify that P5–d5 is okay, but that d5–P5 is incorrect. Allegedly, since we're moving *into* the P5 in this latter instance, that's what makes the voice leading more problematic. In any event, your part writing here would still be correct.
- Still others think that *any* parallel motion between fifths, including P5–d5, is incorrect. If this is the case, then your part writing is not correct.

In my opinion, compositional practice from this time period proves again and again that the third option is far too strict. I'm personally in the first camp, but I know many that are in the second camp. The good news is that the first two camps allow your voice leading; as such, unless you have a *really* strict (and relatively uncommon) teacher/textbook that falls in line with the third camp, your progression is fine.